# Initialise an Stl Vector of type T* from an array of type T

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++11, stl

if I have an array such as:

```
struct S {... };

S m_aArr[256];
```

and I want to use this to construct a vector such as:

```
std::vector<S*> m_vecS;
```

Is there anyway to do this rather than looping through and pushing back `&m_aArr[i]` ?
I understand that I cannot use the conventional method of using `std::begin` and `std::end` on the array since the vector is one of pointers and the original array is one of objects, and so we cannot just pass in a block of memory.

Comment: would that be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434196/how-to-initialize-stdvector-from-c-style-array ?

Comment: `for (S& s : m_aArr) m_vesS.push_back(&s)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the standard library to do the iteration and pushing back for you:

```
std::transform(std::begin(m_aArr), std::end(m_aArr),
               std::back_inserter(m_vecS), std::addressof<S>);
```

This will transform each of the elements in `m_aArr` by applying the [`std::addressof<S>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) function to them. Each of the transformed elements is then `push_back`ed into `m_vecS` by the [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) iterator.

To do this prior to C++11, you won't have access to `std::begin`, `std::end`, or `std::addressof`, so it'll look more like this:

```
std::transform(m_aArr, m_aArr + 256, std::back_inserter(m_vecS), boost::addressof<S>);
```

This uses [`boost::addressof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof).

Comment: +1 - I was going to suggest a similar thing but with a lambda - I didn't even know `std::addressof` existed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Of course, not sure why I didn't do that in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: @Yuushi `std::addressof` works even if `operator&` is overloaded for `S` - so it's superior in this case.

Comment: Thank you, a very elegant solution

Comment: it would be nice to have a `std::valueof` that does the reverse so that you could also push the results back into some other vector (e.g. after sorting a vector of pointers to big data)

Comment: Does this answer the question? The OP wants to **construct** a `vector` with certain properties. Not take an already constructed vector and insert those elements.

Comment: @Walter The initial vector is empty. The transformed elements are put in the vector by `push_back`.

Comment: @Walter I think they are using the term "construct" loosely. They just want to set up the vector in one way or another to have these specific pointers in it.

Comment: Even before C++11, we can easily learn the size of an array. `template<typename T, size_t N> size_t array_length(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }`  This would be useful instead of the explicit `256` in the current answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could let [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) perform the loop:

```
transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(v), 
          [] (S& s) { return &s; });
```

Notice, that you do not need to fully qualify the name `std::transform`, because the function name will by found by [ADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).

This is a complete program to test its behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // <== Required for std::transform
#include <iterator>  // <== Required for std::back_inserter, std::begin, std::end

struct S
{
    S() : i(0) { }
    S(int i_) : i(i_) { }
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    S a[256] = { 42 }; // Copy-initializes first element from 42,
                       // default-constructs all other elements

    std::vector<S*> v;
    transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(v), 
              [] (S& s) { return &s; });

    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; // Prints 256
    std::cout << v[0]->i << std::endl; // Prints 42
    std::cout << v[1]->i << std::endl; // Prints 0
}
```

And here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/q9oiLO).

Comment: Cheers, this is a good idea. I am beginning to realise the power of std::transform

Comment: why are you typing out `std::` prefixes all over this sample, except for `transform` where you rely on ADL? E.g. what if the call to `transform` happened in some generic piece of code where you could not be sure to have arguments that live in namespace `std`?

Comment: @rhalbersma: Well, that's because in the other places it is necessary. It would not be if I used some `using` declarations or `using` directives, and I could - there is no particular reason why I am not using them here, this is just a demonstration. Also, it is enough that *one* argument lives in the `std` namespace for `ADL` to lookup `transform` in `std`, and the result of `std::back_inserter` does live in `std`, no matter where the call is performed.

Comment: I understand your argument, but why bring ADL into play when you don't have to rely on it? Some refactoring later and there is not longer a back inserter etc. Typing `std::` takes 5 keystrokes, and it will always get it right (unless you actually want to also be able to call user-defined versions of `transform`).

Comment: @rhalbersma: Well, I see your point. I sometimes prefer to spare those 5 characters, but yes, not the best example here

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [`std::generate_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) that performs the single allocation of the `std::vector` instead of potentially multiple via [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    struct S {};
    S a[128];
    S* ap = a;

    std::vector<S*> v(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    std::generate_n(std::begin(v), v.size(), [&]() { return ap++; });

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (&a[i] != v[i]) // Ensure same address at each element.
        {
            std::cerr << "Error\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See online at http://ideone.com/73nKST .

Comment: I hand't heard of generate_n before, that sure looks like a useful function. Cheers.