# Uniform initialization with Eigen dynamic types

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

I'm trying to learn the Eigen C++ library, and was wondering if there is some nice shorthand for initializing dynamic vectors and matrices. It would be really nice to write something like you would using a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> myVec = {1,2,3,6,5,4,6};
```

i.e.

```
VectorXi x = {1,2,3,4,7,5,7};
```

The closest (ugly) equivalent I can find involves `Map` . .

```
int xc[] = {2,3,1,4,5};
Map<VectorXi> x(xc,sizeof(xc)/sizeof(xc[0]));
```

What other initialization methods are there?

Comment: Unfortunately, to be backward compatible I guess, uniform initialization depends on the type having a constructor taking an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) instance. If a library haven't been updated to use it then you can't use uniform initialization.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed size matrices/vectors, you can use the comma initializer:

```
Matrix3f m;
m<<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

I can't test it right now, but it should work similarly for your situation:

```
VectorXi x(5);
x << 2,3,1,4,5;
```

If it does not, you could use a temporary Vector, fill it with the five elements using the comma initializer and then assign it to the VectorXi.

edit: 
You might also be interested in this page: [Eigen: Advanced Initialization](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html)

Comment: you have to set the matrix or vector to the correct size before using the comma initializer.

Comment: Ah right, that would be `VectorXi x(5);`. But for the Matrix3f (or any other fixed-size type), no size is needed in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

By the code you showed, you are OK in writing  const items. So maybe you can do something like

```
std::vector<int> vec;
const int init_vec[5] =  {1,2,3,4,5}
vec.assign(init_vec, init_vec + 5);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434196/how-to-initialize-stdvector-from-c-style-array) of how use array to populate vectors.

EDIT: Correct a wrong link formating.