# c++ float* array as reference to std::vector<float>

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, stdvector

I want to create a `std::vector<float> vpd` which will be a reference to `float*`.

```
float * old = new float[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    old[i] = i;
}
vector<float> vpd(6);
auto refasd = &*vpd.begin();
*refasd = *old;
vpd[0] = 23;
cout << old[0] << endl;
```

How should I modify the code, if I want get `23` from `cout`?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434196/how-to-initialize-stdvector-from-c-style-array

Comment: Is it about telling the vector to use your "preallocated" buffer instead of the one a vector manages internally, or is it just that you want to refer to to the vector's internal buffer in terms of a `float*`-type?

Comment: maybe you meant `vpd[0] = 23; *old = *refasd;` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. `std::vector` is not designed to take ownership of a raw pointer.
Maybe you can make do with `std::unique_ptr<float[]>`, but the better solution is to directly use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

As alternative, you might use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (C++20)

```
float* old = new float[6];
std::iota(old, old + 6, 0);
std::span<float> vpd(old, 6);
vpd[0] = 23;
std::cout << old[0] << std::endl;
delete[] old;
```

Comment: Plus one from the future. Does `span` own the memory, i.e. is the `delete[]` intentionally missing?

Comment: Span does not own the memory if I'm not mistaken, so yeah, a `delete[]` is missing.

Answer (score 4):

You could also create a `vector` of `std::reference_wrapper` objects that refer to the original `float` array - may that be `std::vector<float>` or a `new`ed `float*`. An example:

```
vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>> vpd(old, old + 6); // ¹

vpd[0].get() = 23.f;

cout << old[0] << endl; // prints 23
```

¹) Thanks to @StoryTeller for pointing out that `vpd` can be directly initialized.

Comment: I'm not sure you need `std::transform`. IIRC `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>> vpd(old, old + 6);` should work out of the box.

Comment: @StoryTeller True, that's a nice improvement!

Answer (score 2):

As `std::vector` has its own memory structure you cannot map `vector<float>` or even `vector<float*>` to an array of float. However you can map each vector item to an array one.

```
float* old = new float[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    old[i] = i;
}
vector<float*> vpd(6);
int i = 0;
for (auto it = vpd.begin(); it != vpd.end(); it++)
{
    *it = &old[i++];
}
*vpd[0] = 23;
*vpd[2] = 45;
cout << old[0] << endl << old[2] << endl;
```

Output

```
23
45
```

Comment: You ruined your cache locality by doing this, though

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit cold you please explain in more details?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the link is cool in design context however I still don't see the relation with reusing of some memory piece accessed by pointers.

Comment: The entire article is about how indirection in your containers reduces performance by thwarting your CPU's cache. Pointers in contiguous containers should be avoided unless necessary for some goal. A contiguous set of data means the cache will function properly when you obtain the first element; that is, the second and third and maybe more will already be ready for reading. If you are extracting pointers and have to dereference each one, the odds of that information being in cache each time are low (unless the "real" data is nearby) so you will have lots of cache misses. This is expensive.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did I understand correctly: the `vector<MyClass*>` is more expensive that `vector<MyClass>` with move semantic of `MyClass`? Does `vec.puch_back(new MyClass())` is worse that `vec.push_back(std::move(myClassVar))`?

Comment: Now you're talking about the cost of _creating_ those elements, not the cost of accessing them. But the answer is still yes.

Comment: I mean the cost of accessing after creating the objects in both cases.

Comment: Very interesting point, I think it will be fine if you present a small test that can show the difference. For example, two vectors with 1M of objects. I will try to test it, too.

Comment: This has been well documented elsewhere.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit very good point, thank you. [My tests confirm](https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1648), too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I added [a little test](https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1648) on `std::reverse` and the pointer list is much faster. Seems that move semantics is not always performant comparing "old school".

Comment: Sorry I don't get it - I don't believe I suggested moving anything

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry, nothing personal, the point is only to see is my test correct. I seem that majority of algorithms using item reallocation (reverse, sort etc.) will be slower with move semantics than with pointers.

Comment: Okay yeah that may be true but for me it's more about the performance of _using_ the resulting container. Depends on your use case ofc!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version of C++ you'll have some options (if I understand the problem):
if you have an older c++ version then c++11 I would in this case declear std::vector as:

```
// then you really need to make sure u delete the memory as well
std::vector<float*> vpd(6);
```

If however you got c++11 or higher I would use either std::share_ptr or std::unique_ptr depending on if you would like to share the memory space or not. Either this will ensure the memory is deleted by it self without having to do a "delete float*;" which is nice.
You can read about std::shared_ptr at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

```
// For unique_ptr
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<float>> vpd(6);
// for std::shared_ptr
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<float>> vpd(6);
```

I would say that if you can then use unique_ptr rather then shared_ptr due to shared_ptr has som extra komplexitity within to be make sure the memory not used before deleteing memory space.