# C++: Allocate memory for an std::vector then initialize its elements in parallel

Tags: c++, vector, openmp

I have a use case for creating an `std::vector` with *many* elements, each of which is of a simple, but non-primitive, type (POD struct).  The vector and type are sufficiently large/complex that in the following,

```cpp
std::vector<U> v;
v.resize(1000000000);
for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i){/* initialize v[i] */}
```

the `resize` call is noticeably slow.  And it's wasteful because `resize` is default-initializing all those entries, then I'm going through in a loop and setting them all to their correct/useful values.

What I would like to do is to allocate all the memory for the vector, but not initialize any of the entries, then go through in parallel and initialize all the entries, e.g. with OpenMP

```cpp
std::vector<U> v;
v.reserve(1000000000);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i){/* initialize v[i] */}
```

However, `reserve` doesn't actually change the size of `v`, so I'd have to keep doing `push_back` in my loop, which won't maintain the proper ordering of the elements (which matters in my use case); I really want to write something like `v[i] = ...` in my loop body.

Is there a way to allocate/"initialize" a vector without initializing any of its elements, and to then fill in / initialize all the elements in parallel?

Comment: If you have POD then default ctor does nothing, does it not?

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica Typically a vector implementation will call `memset` on POD types which while fast will still have some cost.

Comment: If you know the size you need, why not use an old fashioned array instead?

Comment: @Born2Smile An array that large will come with its own problems, notably if it's too large, you can overrun the stack.

Comment: @Chipster, so don't put it on the stack. `auto v = std::make_shared<U[]>(1000000000)`

Comment: @Born2Smile, well, true. But that isn't the only problem. There is also the problem that [dynamically allocated and normal arrays will still default construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380836/c-allocate-memory-for-an-stdvector-then-initialize-its-elements-in-parallel?noredirect=1#comment104953941_59380989), which the OP expressed an interest in not doing.

Comment: You could allocate your data with `new`, initialize that in parallel (to get first-touch NUMA-friendly behavior) then convert it to `std::vector` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434196/how-to-initialize-stdvector-from-c-style-array.

Comment: @JeffHammond Not sure if this changed in the meantime, but the answers behind that link only discuss solutions that initialize a vector from a C-style array by copying which would in turn undo the NUMA-friendliness...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are:

- Replace `std::vector` with an alternative (e.g. [uvector](http://andreoffringa.org/?q=uvector))
- Use some sort of library to resize without initialization, such as [UninitializedMemoryHacks](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/memory/UninitializedMemoryHacks.h) from Facebook.

After you've performed the resize, you can use OpenMP in the usual ways.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the default constructor for your type U.
If the default constructor is cheap, it is very unlikely that you will gain anything parallelizing it.

```
struct U {
   int a, b, c;
   U():a(0), b(1), c(2) {}
};
```

If your default constructor is expensive, it would make more sense to split it in two parts: One for default initialization and a function for the actual initialization.

```
struct U {
   vector<int> a;
   U() {}
   void init(int n) { a.resize(n); }
};
```

In both alternatives, the regular resize or assign call to the vector would be very hard to beat.

If you really are set in doing things this way, you could use a reinterpret_cast to an array. This way, the default constructor won't be called.

```
U * u_array = reinterpret_cast<U*>(malloc(100*sizeof(U)));
```

I strongly advise against this last option.

Comment: Note that the `malloc` solution would ideally have `struct U` containing only POD types. With `U` containing a `std::vector` as listed, you'd have to jump some extra hoops to release the resources held by `vector` within `U` before `free` is called on your `malloc`'d array. Not to mention the hoops to jump to construct `U` in your array.

Comment: You are totally correct. You really need to know what you are doing when you use an reinterpret_cast.