# How do you properly send an array from ROS in C++?

Tags: c++, ros

I'm using Kinetic.

I have a custom message `path.msg`

```
string path_name
segment[] segments
```

I'm trying to send a ROS goal with that message type.

I initialize an array in my code

```
cuarl_rover_planner::segment segments[path->getSegments().size()];
//do stuff that populates the array
cuarl_rover_planner::path action_path;
action_path.segments = segments; // Error here
```

I get this error

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘cuarl_rover_planner::path_<std::allocator<void> >::_segments_type {aka std::vector<cuarl_rover_planner::segment_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<cuarl_rover_planner::segment_<std::allocator<void> > > >}’ and ‘cuarl_rover_planner::segment [(<anonymous> + 1)] {aka cuarl_rover_planner::segment_<std::allocator<void> > [(<anonymous> + 1)]}’)
         action_path.segments = segments;
```

I'm assuming that the `action_path.segments` take a different data type, but I don't understand what that datatype is, from that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action_path.segments` is a `std::vector<segment>`, but your `segments` variable is just a single segment, not a vector of segments. If you want to add only one segment, you can use `action_path.push_back(segment)`. Otherwise, you can declare `segments` as

```
std::vector<cuarl_rover_planner::segment> segments(path->getSegments().size());
```

If you wanted to use a raw pointer array for some reason (like you might be here), you have to explicitly set that up as `std::vector` first, i.e.

```
action_path.segments = std::vector<cuarl_rover_planner::segment>(segments, segments+path->getSegments().size());
```

See [How to initialize std::vector from C-style array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434196/how-to-initialize-stdvector-from-c-style-array) for more about setting a vector from a raw C-array.