# Test Driven Development with C++

Tags: c++, tdd, cppunit

Looking to start doing TDD in C++. I've seen CPPUnit, but I was wondering if there are other options that people prefer?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you just looking for C++ unit test frameworks? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework

Comment: Looks great. Wanna post as an answer, and I'll accept?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can recommend [Google Mock](https://github.com/google/googletest), which has become part of Google Test bundled. We switched from UnitTest++ to Google Test/Google Mock a couple of years ago and have never looked back.

Google Mock can be used even if you don't want to use the mocking facilities. Its [matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#matchers-matcherlist) are [very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797990/49972).

Comment: I'm not seeing any way to add time constraints which is a pretty big deal in my testing. Am I just missing it?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to measure elapsed time for the code you want to test and then use EXPECT_LT to verify your timing requirement.

Answer (score 10):

I switched from CppUnit to boost::test some years ago and I'm much happier with it.

- Documentation for CppUnit is nonexistent.  Good luck [trying to find out](http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=cppunit+command+line+options&aq=1v&aqi=g1g-v1&aql=&oq=CppUnit+command+line+) what command line options it supports without reading the code.  Apparently it makes more sense to people already familiar with JUnit though.  boost::test has excellent [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).
- boost::test's auto test registration [facility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/auto-nullary-test-case.html) makes adding unit test cases insanely easy.  With CppUnit you have to write quite a lot of boilerplate for each test case (a line in the header and a line it the .cpp to register it, on top of the test method itself).
- boost::test [lets you](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html) select test subsets by regexp from the commandline.  We had to hack CppUnit sources to get it to do that when we originally picked it up.
- The *one* thing I do [miss](http://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/22da8fe9b8e3763d/fcbe6aaa0275fb6e?lnk=raot&pli=1) from CppUnit is its "[Protectors](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jeffery/courses/371/cppunit/class_protector.html)".  You can define your own and have them wrap each test and check whatever (e.g we had a problem with some code messing with the x87 floating point rounding mode; checking the state was unchanged in a Protector quickly caught all offenders).  boost::test has some similar thing called a [`test_observer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/test/test_observer.hpp) but last time I tried you couldn't actually fail a test from one.

Comment: I like gtest better than CppUnit for almost all of the same reasons here, gtest also wraps each test in SEH so access violations don't stop all tests.

Answer (score 6):

If you are just looking for C++ unit test frameworks, see this question and its answers: [C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)

Comment: Note that the comment in that thread that boost::test cannot run tests by name is no longer accurate.

Comment: @timday: Thanks for pointing that out. @hahuang65: The accepted answer there isn't necessarily the best. I'd recommend reviewing all the answers.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for all the answers guys.