# How does gtest compare the values in two arrays?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have read [this official document](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#assertions), learn how to do Binary Comparison and String Comparison.

The ASSERT_EQ and ASSERT_STREQ could not work in the array comparison case.

For example

```
li@li:~/poc$ g++ -I${GTEST_DIR}/include insertion_sort.cpp insertion_sort_unittest.cpp /home/li/libgtest.a -lpthread -o inser_unit
li@li:~/poc$ ./inser_unit 
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from InsertionSortTest
[ RUN      ] InsertionSortTest.Two
insertion_sort_unittest.cpp:18: Failure
Value of: two_sorted
  Actual: { 2, 5 }
Expected: two
Which is: { 2, 5 }
[  FAILED  ] InsertionSortTest.Two (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from InsertionSortTest (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] InsertionSortTest.Two

 1 FAILED TEST
```

insertion_sort_unittest.cpp

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "insertionsort.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

namespace{
    class InsertionSortTest : public ::testing::Test{
        protected:
            InsertionSortTest() {}
            virtual ~InsertionSortTest() {}
            virtual void SetUp() {}
            virtual void TearDown() {}
    };

    TEST(InsertionSortTest, Two){
        int two[] = {5, 2};
        int two_sorted[] = {2, 5};
        insertionSort(two, 2);
        EXPECT_EQ(two, two_sorted);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

insertion_sort.cpp

```
#include "insertionsort.h"
void insertionSort(int *data, int size){
    for (int i=1,j; i<size; i++){
        int key = data[i];
        for (j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
            if (data[j] > key){
                data[j+1]=data[j];
                data[j]=key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

insertionsort.h

```
#ifndef INSERTIONSORT_H_
#define INSERTIONSORT_H_
void insertionSort(int *data, int size);
#endif
```

Comment: Maybe I should learn how to use googlemock, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460703/comparison-of-arrays-in-google-test) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=231)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to add a dependency on googlemock if you don't want, you could write your own simple function that returns a `testing::AssertionResult`, e.g.

```
    template<typename T, size_t size>
    ::testing::AssertionResult ArraysMatch(const T (&expected)[size],
                                           const T (&actual)[size]){
        for (size_t i(0); i < size; ++i){
            if (expected[i] != actual[i]){
                return ::testing::AssertionFailure() << "array[" << i
                    << "] (" << actual[i] << ") != expected[" << i
                    << "] (" << expected[i] << ")";
            }
        }

        return ::testing::AssertionSuccess();
    }
```

Then in your test, call:

```
    EXPECT_TRUE(ArraysMatch(two_sorted, two));
```

Comment: Compiling using MVSC (with gmock 1.11.0) returns error `error C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type '_Ty'`, having to do with the custom string that was directed to `::testing::AssertionFailure()`. Any idea why is this?

Answer (score 9):

`ASSERT_EQ` compares its arguments using `operator==`. Comparing with `operator==` works for `std::vector`'s but not for C-arrays in C++. The reason is, when you try to use a value of a C-array in an expression, in most circumstances the value decays into a pointer pointing to the beginning of the memory where the array is stored. You end up comparing two pointers. In case of two different C-arrays those pointers will never have the same value.

Your easiest way out is to use Google Mock's `ASSERT_THAT` macro and the [ContainerEq](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#container-matchers) matcher. Instead of `ASSERT_EQ`, write

```
ASSERT_THAT(two, ContainerEq(two_sorted));
```

Comment: Just to clarify - this still doesn't work on C arrays, right? because there's nowhere to pass the length of the array(s)?

Comment: It does - see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/786564fa4a3c8e0f908acca32cce481de5481b9f/googlemock/test/gmock-matchers_test.cc#L4311.

Comment: Oh, no way! I could've sworn I tried it, but I'll have to double-check. Maybe I just assumed it wouldn't work. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 5):

I think it is enough to write just like this.

`EXPECT_EQ(memcmp(two, two_sorted, 2 * sizeof(int)), 0);`