# Comparison of floating point arrays using google test and google mock

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, googletest, googlemock

I am new to Google's test products and trying them out with some signal processing code. I am trying to assert that to floating point arrays are equal to within some bounds, using google mock as suggested by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460703/comparison-of-arrays-in-google-test). I would like to know the recommended method for adding some error tolerance to an expression like the following . . .

```
EXPECT_THAT(  impulse, testing::ElementsAreArray( std::vector<float>({
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}) )  );
```

I want the test to pass if the element-wise values in the arrays are within 10<sup>-8</sup> of one another.

Comment: Wacked in an exponentation. Roll back if it's unwanted. By the way, what's your science behind that tolerance?

Answer (score 8):

The following works for me:

```
using ::testing::Pointwise;
using ::testing::FloatNear;

auto const max_abs_error = 1 / 1024.f;
ASSERT_THAT(
    test,
    Pointwise(FloatNear(max_abs_error), ref));
```

Where `test` and `ref` are of type `std::vector<float>`.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use the googletest rather than googlemock macros, which results in a more compact assert:

```
#define EXPECT_FLOATS_NEARLY_EQ(expected, actual, thresh) \
        EXPECT_EQ(expected.size(), actual.size()) << "Array sizes differ.";\
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < std::min(expected.size(), actual.size()); ++idx) \
        { \
            EXPECT_NEAR(expected[idx], actual[idx], thresh) << "at index: " << idx;\
        }

// define expected_array as in the other answer
EXPECT_FLOATS_NEARLY_EQ(impulse, expected_array, 0.001);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method. First define a matcher outside of the test scope. According to the documentation, the matcher cannot be defined in a class or function . .

```
MATCHER_P(FloatNearPointwise, tol, "Out of range") {
    return (std::get<0>(arg)>std::get<1>(arg)-tol && std::get<0>(arg)<std::get<1>(arg)+tol) ;
}
```

Then is can be used with `Pointwise` int the test . . .

```
std::vector<float> expected_array({
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
});

EXPECT_THAT(  impulse, Pointwise( FloatNearPointwise(1e-8), expected_array  ) );
```

But it would be neater if there was a solution that used the builtin `FloatNear` directly.

Comment: Note: Pointwise is in testing namespace `::testing::Pointwise`

Comment: nit: The string given to `MATCHER_P` should describe the matcher's *passing* criteria, not it's failing criteria.